# Oracle XMLTable() to Correlate with Previous Node with Specific Tag?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, xmltable

I have XML data where parent-child relationship was maintained based on the position in them XML (the child elements belong to the previous parent until the next parent is seen). Is it possible to use `XMLTable()` to do this?

Consider the following sample XML

```
<myData>
   <myParent>
      <parentID>H1</parentID>
      <parentName>Header 1</parentName>
   </myParent>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D1</childID>
      <childName>Detail D1</childName>
   </myChild>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D2</childID>
      <childName>Detail D2</childName>
   </myChild>
   <myParent>
      <parentID>H2</parentID>
      <parentName>Header 2</parentName>
   </myParent>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D3</childID>
      <childName>Detail D3</childName>
   </myChild>
</myData>
```

I want is something like

```
PARENTID    CHILDID     CHILDNAME
----------- ----------- ----------------------
H1          D1          Detail D1
H1          D2          Detail D2
H2          D3          Detail D3
```

The most preferred way is to a select statement, though other methods (e.g., table function, ref cursor) are also helpful.

I can extract the parents and children as tables separately. However, due to the XML design, I can't find a key to join between them.

```
with xml as (
select xmltype(
'<myData>
   <myParent>
      <parentID>H1</parentID>
      <parentName>Header 1</parentName>
   </myParent>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D1</childID>
      <childName>Detail D1</childName>
   </myChild>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D2</childID>
      <childName>Detail D2</childName>
   </myChild>
   <myParent>
      <parentID>H2</parentID>
      <parentName>Header 2</parentName>
   </myParent>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D3</childID>
      <childName>Detail D3</childName>
   </myChild>
</myData>') data
from dual
)
select child.* from xml,
--XMLTable for header
--xmltable('myData/myParent' passing
--xml.data
--columns row_num for ordinality,
--         "parentID",
--         "parentName"
--) parent,
--XMLTable for detail
xmltable('myData/myChild' passing
xml.data
columns row_num for ordinality,
         "childID",
         "childName"
) child;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XRel0hoe)

This outputs the only children as a table. (Commented out section is another `XMLTable()` to extract the parent. However, there is no way to join the two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LAST_VALUE to get the nearest parent before the children (by row_num) :

```
with xml as (
select xmltype(
'<myData>
   <myParent>
      <parentID>H1</parentID>
      <parentName>Header 1</parentName>
   </myParent>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D1</childID>
      <childName>Detail D1</childName>
   </myChild>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D2</childID>
      <childName>Detail D2</childName>
   </myChild>
   <myParent>
      <parentID>H2</parentID>
      <parentName>Header 2</parentName>
   </myParent>
   <myChild>
      <childID>D3</childID>
      <childName>Detail D3</childName>
   </myChild>
</myData>') data
from dual
)
, expanded AS (
    SELECT rn, childid, childname, parentid, parentname, 
        LAST_VALUE(parentid IGNORE NULLS)
            OVER(ORDER BY RN ) AS latestparentid
    FROM xml, 
    xmltable('myData/*' passing
        xml.data
        columns rn for ordinality,
        childid PATH 'childID' ,
        childname PATH 'childName',
        parentid PATH 'parentID',
        parentname PATH 'parentName'
    ) node
)
SELECT p.parentid, p.parentname, c.childid, c.childname
FROM expanded p 
JOIN expanded c ON p.parentid = c.latestparentid
WHERE p.parentid IS NOT NULL
;


H1  Header 1        
H1  Header 1    D1  Detail D1
H1  Header 1    D2  Detail D2
H2  Header 2        
H2  Header 2    D3  Detail D3
```

Comment: This worked for my case and I marked accepted. Meanwhile, I have a followup question: what if the inner tag names are the same in parent and child elements (say, instead of `parentID`/`childID` and `parentName`/`childName`, the tags are simply named `ID` and `Name`)?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the subsidiary question "what if the inner tag names are the same in parent and child elements":

```
with xml (data) as (
  select '<myData>
   <myParent>
      <ID>H1</ID>
      <Name>Header 1</Name>
   </myParent>
   <myChild>
      <ID>D1</ID>
      <Name>Detail D1</Name>
   </myChild>
   <myChild>
      <ID>D2</ID>
      <Name>Detail D2</Name>
   </myChild>
   <myParent>
      <ID>H2</ID>
      <Name>Header 2</Name>
   </myParent>
   <myChild>
      <ID>D3</ID>
      <Name>Detail D3</Name>
   </myChild>
</myData>' from dual
)
, expanded as (
    select x.rn, x.id, x.name, x.kind, 
        LAST_VALUE(case kind when 'myParent' then id end IGNORE NULLS)
            OVER(ORDER BY RN ) AS latestparentid
    from xml d
    cross join xmltable(
      '//myData/*'
      passing xmltype(d.data)
        columns 
            rn for ordinality,
            id PATH 'ID',
            name PATH 'Name',
            kind varchar2(20) PATH 'local-name()'
    ) x
)
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.id as childid, c.name as childname
FROM expanded p 
JOIN expanded c ON p.id = c.latestparentid AND c.kind = 'myChild'
WHERE p.kind = 'myParent'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a frame challenge, don't format your XML like that. Instead, nest the children in the parent:

```xml
<myData>
   <myParent>
      <parentID>H1</parentID>
      <parentName>Header 1</parentName>
      <children>
         <myChild>
            <childID>D1</childID>
            <childName>Detail D1</childName>
         </myChild>
         <myChild>
            <childID>D2</childID>
            <childName>Detail D2</childName>
         </myChild>
      </children>
   </myParent>
   <myParent>
      <parentID>H2</parentID>
      <parentName>Header 2</parentName>
      <children>
         <myChild>
            <childID>D3</childID>
            <childName>Detail D3</childName>
         </myChild>
      </children>
   </myParent>
</myData>
```

Then you can use:

```sql
select p.row_num,
       p.parentid,
       p.parentname,
       c.*
from   xml
       CROSS APPLY xmltable(
         '/myData/myParent'
         passing xml.data
         COLUMNS
           row_num for ordinality,
           parentId   VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'parentID',
           parentName VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'parentName',
           children   XMLTYPE      PATH 'children'
       ) p
       CROSS APPLY xmltable(
         '/children/myChild'
         passing p.children
         COLUMNS
           row_num for ordinality,
           childId    VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'childID',
           childName  VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'childName'
       ) c;
```

Which outputs:

| ROW_NUM | PARENTID | PARENTNAME | ROW_NUM | CHILDID | CHILDNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H1 | Header 1 | 1 | D1 | Detail D1 |
| 1 | H1 | Header 1 | 2 | D2 | Detail D2 |
| 2 | H2 | Header 2 | 1 | D3 | Detail D3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vh6bdhve)

---

Theoretically, with your format, you would get the preceding `myParent` sibling and could use the query:

```sql
select c.*
from   xml
       CROSS APPLY xmltable(
         '/myData/myChild'
         passing xml.data
         COLUMNS
           row_num for ordinality,
           parentId   VARCHAR2(10) PATH './preceding-sibling::myParent/parentID',
           parentName VARCHAR2(50) PATH './preceding-sibling::myParent/parentName',
           childId    VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'childID',
           childName  VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'childName'
       ) c;
```

However, Oracle does not appear to support the `preceding-sibling::*` syntax so the `parent*` columns are all returned as `NULL` and, unfortunately, the query does not work.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nUVNkucT)

Comment: I can't modify the XML format. The `preceding-sibling` syntax is interesting, too bad Oracle does not support that.